# "Calculus" of metric entropy: How does metric entropy behave with respect to binary operators?

Tags: reference-request, fa.functional-analysis, real-analysis, entropy, function-spaces

This is a general question, more of a reference request. **tl;dr:** Is there a "calculus" for computing metric entropy bounds?

Given a function space $\mathcal{F}$, we may define its metric entropy. Suppose we have two function spaces $(\mathcal{F},\rho)$ and $(\mathcal{G},\rho)$ with known metric entropies $\mathcal{N}(\epsilon,\mathcal{F},\rho)$ and $\mathcal{N}(\epsilon,\mathcal{G},\rho)$. Here, $\rho$ is a common metric on both spaces. We can form new function spaces from these spaces by taking sums, (algebraic) products, direct products, convolutions, etc. I am interested in expression for the metric entropy of these "new" spaces (under $\rho$) in terms of $\mathcal{N}(\epsilon,\mathcal{F},\rho)$ and $\mathcal{N}(\epsilon,\mathcal{G},\rho)$.

Now, it may not be hard to work out any of these in particular, but I am looking for a reference that collects these together in one place, and preferably discusses even more general relationships between metric entropies of spaces.